# Как из Java кода вызвать JavaScript код в GWT?

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Добрый день. Работаю в eclipse с gwt и у меня возник такой вопрос. В файле Proverka.html есть функция displaymessage. Вот код:

```
function displaymessage()
{
    $.getScript("http://api.wipmania.com/wip.js",
    function()
    {
        alert(WIPlocation.zoom);
    });
}
```

А вот пример Proverka.java:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
public class Proverka implements EntryPoint
{
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        Window.alert("Hello");
    }
}
```

Скажите, можно как-то в методе onModuleLoad вызвать функцию displaymessage?

Comment: Простите за вопрос, но как подключить функцию displaymessage?

Comment: Так добавьте скрипт на страницу и всё

Answer (score 2):

Запросто

```
private native void callDisplayMessage()/*-{
    displaymessage();
}-*/;

public void onModuleLoad()
{
    callDisplayMessage();
}
```

Comment: Скопировал то, что вы написали в файл Proverka.java (Туда-то хоть скопировал? И все ли надо копировать?), после этого выбивает "Uncaught exception escaped ... caused by: ... displaymessage is not defined). Что делать?

Comment: Значит у вас нет функции displaymessage.. подключите её на вашей странице

Comment: Возможно, проблема в неверном порядке подключения скриптов (на момент запуска скрипт с displaymessage ещё не существует

Comment: А как сделать наоборот? Вызвать метод GWT из Javascript?

Comment: Прочтите это: http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75695